# why textInput in react-native with textAlign right does't work well in scroll view? (android only)

Tags: react-native

When a TextInput with has textAlign: 'right' inside a ScrollView and you press on it for scrolling it will focus instead (only on Android).

The correct behaviour would be to get focused only if you tap on it (without scrolling).

if you set these props it is worked

```
multiline={true}
keyboardType={"default"}
```

but my keyboard type is numeric and it's not multi line!

what can i do?